Unreachable service in a podman container running as root
I have a webui in podman container that i want to access through my browser, browser and podman runs on the same machine. I use the following command podman run -p 7860:7860 --gpus all 8b8b975cb65b to run the container. When i use the command as non-root user, the service is accessible from browser, but it's not when i run with sudo as root.
